# Auto populate a table based from datas from another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row

this is the another version of my first question and I hope I can best explain my problem this time.

From the Table 1, I want to auto populate Table 2 based on this conditions and criteria (below)

From the example, I basically have 3 initial criteria, **ON CALL**, **AVAILABLE**, and **BREAK**

Now for the conditions, I want all Agents from status ON CALL, AVAILABLE, BREAK from Table 1 to be populated on Table 2 (optional: If possible, I wanted only to show agents that HAS a duration of 4 minutes and above from each status). My problem is I always refresh TABLE 1 so I can get an updated data. My goal here is to monitor our agents their current Status and Running Duration, and from that I only need to check on the table 2 so I would see right away who has the highest running duration from each status to be called out.

[image]

I only tried MAXIFS function but my problem with it, I can only show 1 result from each status.

What I wanted is to fully populate Table 2 from the data on Table 1. If this is possible with ROW function that would be great, because what I really wanted is a clean Table, and it should only load data if the criteria is met.

Thank you

Comment: did you try the FILTER formula suggested on your last question?

Comment: hi yes I'm sorry, I saw your comment right after I finished posting this new one. I am trying your suggestion now and will give you a feedback ASAP. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, it works perfectly! Now how do I sort them from highest to lowest duration, and given from my example here above, how do I include the name of the "Agent" from the formula you have given? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you may be interested in doing is utilizing `HSTACK`. I am not sure how you are currently obtaining the Agents name in the adjacent column to the results but this would populate both the Agent along with the Duration.

```
=HSTACK(INDEX(A:C,MATCH(SORT(FILTER(C:C,(C:C>=TIMEVALUE("00:04:00"))*(B:B=H2),""),1,1),C:C,0),1),TEXT(SORT(FILTER(C:C,(C:C>=TIMEVALUE("00:04:00"))*(B:B=H2),""),1,1),"[h]:mm:ss"))
```

This formula checks Table 1 for any Agent with the status referenced in `H2` (Available) that also has a time greater than or equal to 4 mins. It then sorts the results in ascending order and populates the Agent Name that is associated with it. It is dynamic and will produce a table like the following:

[image: Example]

Just update the formula to check for "On Call" and "BreaK" as desired for the other two.

**UPDATE:**

As for conditional formatting, this is utilizing the custom formula posted in the comments. If the formatting of the times are of `[h]:mm:ss` then you would be looking to do something like this. Notice the 2 cells are highlighted for being between 4 mins and 5 mins.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this looks more amazing than the previous one but both great, let me try this and will give you feedback afterwards. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Kevin P. this works best! I like this more since I am having hard time sorting agents based on their duration. The only problem I am dealing with right now is that I need conditional formatting for the duration that will highlight duration starting 0:04:00 and up. Conditional formatting seems can't recognize the formatting of my duration on the table 2

Comment: Are the values of your time durations formatted as `TEXT` or `TIME`? This would play a role in why the conditional formatting is giving issues.

Comment: If the cells are formatted as `TIME` (I would expect considering you are able to make the formula work) then you would need to look at using `TIME` as part of the conditional formatting. This gets a little fuzzy for sure if you are using a custom formula but here is an example: `=AND(TIMEVALUE(I4)>=TIME(0,4,0),TIMEVALUE(I4)<=TIME(0,5,0))` This will trigger for any value that is greater than or equal to 4 mins and less than or equal to 5 mins. `TIME(h,m,s)`.

Comment: As I checked right now the formatting of my time durations are set to [h]:mm:ss

I am actually getting these datas including the time duration from a website and maybe since this is from an external source (webpage) they have their own formatting. I tried changing the formatting but it's giving me different value so I decided not to touch the original formatting from it's source and leave it that way.

Comment: sorry I didn't realized you already replied an answer, let me check on that and I will get back to you. Anyway all these are great already! Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Take a look at my update to see a screenshot utilizing the formula I posted just above for dealing with times in a conditional formatting.

Comment: sorry I thought I was able to reply last time. the login goes offline! By the way everything works perfectly including my problem with the conditional formatting! Thank you again I learned so much from here!

Comment: By the way, I ran into a problem, the last formula you gave was working properly, now when the value of duration goes over 23:59:59, the 1st array hstack is returning #N/A. The 1st array is the agent's name, and the 2nd array is the duration. The duration and its values is being returned normally, but the 1st array is returning as #N/A.

Comment: This is because the cell is formatted in 24 hour time format. Meaning hours do not exceed 24. You should notice that the cells that did exceed 23:59:59 would now have a date in their value (although hidden unless clicked). Excel starts at 1/1/1900 for the first day after 24 hours and up from there. This date being in the value is throwing off the formula. I updated the formula to account for that. Apologies, I should have caught that sooner. : )

Comment: I am also wondering the whole-time why I can't seem to have a proper format of my duration when it exceeds 24hr and clueless where this 1/1/1900 is coming from. Now I know! And this is a very good knowledge to know thank you so much! And the updated formula works perfect! It solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Another thing, right now I just found out I am getting an issue whenever I am getting a duplicate value of duration. Every time this happen, my agent's name is getting an issue, I am getting 2 the same value of duration which is fine because it can really happen, but I am also getting 2 the same agents name (same value) instead of 2 agents that is different to each other. That make sense because these 2 agents have the same duration but how would I be able to show 2 different agent with the same duration value?

Answer (score 1):

This is an array solution that spill all the results at once. We use a user `LAMBDA` function `GET` to avoid repetition of the same calculation using as input parameter the status (`s`). The formula works for durations in time format or in text format with a minor modification. On cell `E2` put the following formula for durations in time format:

```
=LET(GET, LAMBDA(s, FILTER(HSTACK(A:A, C:C), (B:B=s) 
  * IFERROR(C:C >= TIME(0,4,0), FALSE))), 
 IFERROR(HSTACK(GET("ON CALL"), GET("Available"), GET("Break")),""))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

For durations as text in `hh:mm:ss` format just replace: `C:C >= TIME(0,4,0)` with `TIMEVALUE(C:C) >= TIME(0,4,0)`.

The `GET` function is reused to generate the result for each status. The last `IFERROR` call is used to remove `#N/A` values generated by `HSTACK` when the column doesn't have the maximum number of rows of the output.

The first `IFERROR` is used to treat the case when the value is not numeric, such has the header. This is because we are using the entire column as input range. Using entire columns produce more concise formulas with less maintenance effort, *but it is less efficient*, unless you have a good reason to have an open range. If you want to use a specific range instead for the data of the table, then you can remove it and update the ranges accordingly.

Comment: Hi! Really appreciate your response, yours looks very advanced to me though I tried it unfortunately I can't make it work. I will for sure going to use one of this kind in the future! Thank you so much sir!

Comment: @Harvey probably you have some excel version limitation, I am assuming Office 365, do you have a different version?

Comment: I am currently using Office 365. I don't have any other version at the moment sir

Comment: @Harvey, please share a link (editable) of your file, it could be just a sample where you can show the issue